# Batch delete rows matching multiple columns in postgres using an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, supabase, supabase-database

i'd like to delete these rows from a table in a postgres function as an array parameter:

```
  {id1: 4, id2: 8}
  {id1: 4, id2: 9}
  {id1: 5, id2: 8}
```

that is, something like this:

```
delete from mytable 
where (id1, id2) = ANY(Array [(4,8), (4,9), (5,8)])
```

<del>which doesn't work*</del> UPDATE: [yes it does](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZeUNdEns), [but not in supabase](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/12158). see below

but i know you can do this:

```
delete from mytable 
where (id1, id2) in ((4,8), (4,9), (5,8))
```

and this:

```
delete from othertable 
where id = ANY(Array [1,2])
```

i'd love to know if anyone has insight on how to accurately combine these.  i've tried every combination i can think of.  maybe i'm missing something obvious, or maybe i could use a temporary table somehow?

*the error for that attempt is `cannot compare dissimilar column types bigint and integer at record column 1`, but both column types are definitely bigint

---

## Update:

so actually this works fine, as demonstrated in the comments:

```
delete from mytable where (id1, id2) = ANY(Array [(1,3), (2,1)]);
```

my errors are from a bug in the supabase client that i was using to run postgres commands, i believe.

but here's **a_horse_with_no_name**'s answer (and critical work-around thank you!) implemented in a function, putting here for posterity:

```
create or replace function bulk_delete (id1s bigint [], id2s bigint [])
  returns setof bigint
  language PLPGSQL
  as $$
begin
    return query WITH deleted AS (

      delete from mytable
      where (id1, id2) in (
        select id1, id2
        from unnest(id1s, id2s) as x(id1, id2)
      ) returning *

    ) SELECT count(*) FROM deleted;
end;
$$;

select bulk_delete(Array [1,1], Array [1,2]);
```

response:

```
|bulk_delete|
|-----------|
| 2         |
```

adding my [supabase bug report](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/12158) for completeness

## Update 2

the issue was conflicting types between implied `int`s and supabase's default `int8`

Comment: The first query you mentioned not working .. it is working for me https://dbfiddle.uk/ZeUNdEns

Comment: wow, dang. i'm using a table i generated with supabase, and their sql editor.  retried and got the same error. guess i'll let them know - thank you for checking this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to pass two arrays (of the same length) then unnest them both together so that you can use an IN operator

```
delete from the_table
where (id1, id2) in (select id1, id2
                     from unnest(array_with_id1, array_with_id2) as x(id1, id2);
```